# Extra spacing is observed between text field and <p> element in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to remove extra spacing between text field and paragraph(p) element using CSS? I have specified the height, width and padding in percentages. Spacing is proper between the input elements. But spacing is not proper between the input elelment and paragraph(p) element. Can anyone please tell me the solution.

```
Below is my code snippet:
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
            .mainview{
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            white-space:pre-wrap;
            overflow:scroll;
            padding-top: 5%;
            padding-bottom: 5%;
            background: url(mainview.png);
            position: relative;
        }

        .in{
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 18pt;
            left: 20%;
            right: 20%;
            width:60%;
            position: absolute;

        }

        .dob{
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 18pt;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            left: 20%;
            right: 20%;
            width:60%;
            position: absolute;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainview" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Firstname" class="in" />
            </br>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Lastname" class="in"/>
            </br>
            <p class="dob">DOB</p>
            </br>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="in"/>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I recommend, in addition to posting the code here, also supply an interactive edition using something like Codepen or jsFiddle -- it gives people trying to answer your question a means with which to quickly correct, test, fork, and reply with a solution in a convenient way. I usually don't bother probing questions like these unless I can play with the code conveniently. Meet us half way ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really want that `<p class="dob">DOB</p>` ?
If so change the color of text to black..
Change the dob class as follows:

```
.dob {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 18pt;
color: #000;
left: 20%;
right: 20%;
width: 60%;
position: absolute;
-webkit-margin-before: 0px;
-webkit-margin-after: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the

```
<br/>
```

elements in your html code, they add extra lines.

Comment: Do you really want that <p class="dob">DOB</p> ?

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` might have some padding/margin by default.

Also is recommended to not use `br` (which should be `<br />`, not `</br>` like in your sample)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show just some text use <label> tag instead of <p> tag. also change the color css of 'dob' class to #fff